# retrieve value inside certain pattern

Tags: c#, regex, .net-2.0

i have a pattern as like this

```
"The world is #bright# and #beautiful#"
```

i need to retrieve the string "bright","beautiful" inside # # .. any pointers

---

My solution (thanks to Bolu):

```
string s = "The world is #bright# and #beautiful#";
    string[] str = s.Split('#');
    for (int i = 0; i <= str.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            Response.Write(str[i] + "<br />");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Daren provided a more pertinent answer than I did, but see here for referene to grouping and backreferencing: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Asif, please mark @Bolu's answer (which you used with a slight modification) as accepted.  I've edited your question to include the modification you used.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you want is the string inside ##, then no need for regex, just use string.Split:

```
string rawstring="The world is #bright# and beautiful";
string[] tem=rawstring.Split('#');
```

After that, all you need is to get the even item (with index: 1,3,5....) from the `string[] tem`

Answer (score 4):

As long as you can't have nested `#...#` sequences, `#([^#]+)#` will work, and will capture the content between #'s as the first [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Explanation:

```
#        match a literal # character
(        open a capturing group
  [^     open a negated character class
     #   don't match # (since the character class is negated)
  ]+     close the class, match it one or more times
)        close the capturing group
#        match a literal # character
```

Comment: I'm genuinely confused. Where does the OP say he has nested sequences? Or were you just highlighting this as a potential problem.

Comment: @annakata just highlighting it as a issue that would break the regex.

Comment: @annakata - he is highlighting it as a potential problem. Regular expressions are a sound mathematical thing. If you grok them, you are probably mathematically sound and prone to worrying about potential problems. This is a good thing, but quite often, you can get the job done far quicker without worrying ;)

Comment: This does not capture the string __inside__ the `#..#` but captures the entire match with the `#`'s still there.

Comment: @Callum I added a capturing group.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `Match` object:

```
var match = Regex.Match(yourstring, @"The world is #(.*)# and beautiful")
var bright = match.Groups[1]
```

Of course this breaks down when you have more than two #'s in your string. Then you probably want to do a non-greedy match. This can be done with the regex "`#(.*?)#`". This will match the shortest string between two sharps and still have the contents in the first group.

Comment: +1 But although non-greedy is good, I'd caution against thinking it solves much - false sense of security when you consider nested and unclosed sequences, although of course the OP opens himself up to these by just having the single delimiter I suppose.

Comment: Sometimes systems like these don't have to be totally sound - say you only ever have an "identifier" between the sharps. You could then use `#([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)#` and be over and done with it. I've used stuff like this for simple macro systems before - if you control the input, not much can go wrong...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a `Capturing Group` by wrapping the part you want to capture in round brackets `()` and optionally specifying a name for the capture:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"#([^#]+?)#");
```

which can be accessed by using this code:

```
Match m = r.Match("The world is #bright# and beautiful");
string capture = m.Groups[1];
```

---

Or with a named parameter:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"#(?<mycapture>[^#]+?)#");
```

which can be accessed by using this code:

```
Match m = r.Match("The world is #bright# and beautiful");
string capture = m.Groups["mycapture"];
```