# Regular Expression Match Help

Tags: c#, .net, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string..

"I am a number #Number# and I am a letter #Letter# as a test"

I am trying to use a Regex.Matches to grab the string #Number# and #Letter# out of the string..

Ive tried a bunch of different regular expressions without any luck

Any idea what kind of regular expression pattern to use to pull out the words between the # but include the # on both sides

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736133/retrieve-value-inside-certain-pattern/3736275#3736275

Comment: So you want the matches to return "#Number#" and "#Letter#" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex: `#[^#]*#`. It will match `#Number#` and `#Letter#`.

[image]

Comment: It will also match # and I am a letter #

Comment: @antlersoft, I tested this regex and provided output.

Comment: @LeeHull, You're welcome. @antlersoft, I'm waiting your comments.

Comment: I was wrong, it works on this case-- it is inadequate only in a more general case where other # signs are floating around.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic regex to capture this is:

```
I am a number (#[^#]+#) and I am a letter (#[^#]+#) as a test
```

A successful `Match` object will have `Groups[1]` with your number and `Groups[2]` with your letter.